# Firebase notification LED blink

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, push-notification, led

I'm using Cordova to make a mobile app and I'm trying to send a push notification via [google's Firebase.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging)

I was able to set `title`, `body`, `badge`, `sound`, etc. but I can't figure out how to set a LED blinking when receiving a notification.

I tried using `localNotification`, but it requires the app to be running at all times.

Does any of you have any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late but for other readers:

In the NotificationCompat.Builder add this

```
.setLights(int argb, int onMs, int offMs)
```

Documentation:

> Set the argb value that you would like the LED on the device to blink,
>   as well as the rate.

Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html

Answer (score 0):

This works for us, using [node-gcm](https://github.com/ToothlessGear/node-gcm) on the server:

```
var gcm = require('node-gcm');
var push = new gcm.Message({
  data: {
    title: 'Your app',
    message: message,
    ledColor: [215, 138, 138, 1], //show a blinking LED with given color in ARGB format
  },
});
gcmSender.send(push, [token], function(err, res) {
   console.log(res);
});
```